# HP Spectre x360: no sound with internal speakers and no bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new HP Spectre Laptop x360 - 15t-eb and I face two problems:

1. I have no sound with the internal speakers, but sound is OK with USB speakers or speakers of my monitors (DisplayPort or HDMI). Internal speakers also correctly operates on Windows 10.
2. The bluetooth interface is not detected on Ubuntu, but corretly operates on Windows 10.

I have done all updates of BIOS given by HP without any improvement.

Any ideas to solve these issues?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got sound temporary by run this more than once.

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DIR 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_MASK 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DATA 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DATA 0x00
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_Spectre_x360_(2020)#Audio

My bluetooth works well from the beginning.

Comment: Exact same answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321490/348964) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321484/348964)